# How can i read sms in xamarin forms PCL projects

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sms

i want to read all sms from mobile phone and show in the list on my app. I saw some tutorial using xamarin essential for sms send. How read sms in PCL xamarin forms.

Comment: You cannot do this in iOS.

Comment: Please refer to this:  https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-developer-policy-call-log-sms/